Is this a good way to use a separate validation set with k-fold cross-validation?
I am training a CNN, and I divided the dataset into 70% training set, 20% validation set, and 10% test set. What I want is to use this validation set for early stopping to avoid overfitting the model for every training Iteration. So my approach is as follows:
1- Divide the dataset into Train + Validation + Test sets.
2- Apply K-Fold Cross-Validation only on the training set , where I will train the model on K-1 folds, validate on the remaining fold, and I will use the validation set (held separately for tuning purpose) for early stopping and model checkpoint during each training iteration.
3- After the Cross-Validation process, I will train the model on the entire training set , and then evaluate the model on the test set (which was untouched), while using the validation set for early stopping and model checkpoint.
Is this a good approach ? Or I could use K-Fold CV on the training set, then use the external validation set only once for early stopping during final training on the entire 70% training set, and then evaluate the final model on the test set?  Or is there is another approach that is better than these ones?
